# How do I delete an object if not referenced by another object

Tags: python, sql, django

I have two models similar to this:

```
class ContactDetails(Model):
  name = models.CharField()
  dept = models.CharField()

class Server(Model):
  ip = models.GenericIPAddressField()                           
  hostname = models.CharField()
  contact = models.ForeignKey(ContactDetails)
```

A `ContactDetails` object may be referenced by many Server objects.

When I delete a Server record, I'd like to also delete the associated ContactDetails record.

But only if there are no other Server records referencing that ContactDetails record. What's the best practice way of doing this in Django?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably using either pre_delete or post_delete [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals).

```
from django.db import models
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(models.signals.post_delete, sender=Server)
def delete_contact(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if not Server.objects.filter(contact=instance.contact):
        instance.contact.delete()
```

The instance is the Server instance that has already been removed from the db.

Comment: Also, is there a way to look through all Contact objects and delete any that are not referenced by a Server object? Many thanks.

Comment: Sure - each ContactDetails will have a reverse set back to server, probably called server_set. If its empty, no relationship. I'd advise reading up on all this in the Django docs.